# I open a second view that displays a series of images in a collection, Can I press on an image of the collection for use image in the first view?

Tags: swift, image, return, back

I open a second view that displays a series of images in a collection, Can I press on an image of the collection for use image in the first view?

//from first ViewController

```
@IBAction func backgroundButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

//SecondViewController

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func returnHome(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
......

extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return data.count
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
            cell.data = self.data[indexPath.item]
            return cell
        }
    }


class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        var data: CustomData? {
            didSet {
                guard let data = data else { return }
                bg.image = data.backgroundImage

                let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
                bg.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                bg.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            }
        }

    @objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
        self.addSubview(tappedImage)  
    }
// When I tap on Image in this case addSubview but I want use that image in First View Controller
```

Comment: Please fix your code. It’s almost not readable on a phone

Comment: You mean when you tap image in collection view cell in second view controller and   you wanna use that tapped image in first view controller ?

Comment: yes, image tapped I want to use it as a background image of the first controller